# Access Handling No Current Record

Tags: vba, ms-access, exception

I have the next code:

```vb
If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tbl_F.[Fecha] FROM tbl_F WHERE tbl_F.[Fecha]=#" & Forms!frm_Name!txt_Fecha & "#;").Fields(0) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "This record already exists"
    Else
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
```

The table *table_F* goes like this:

```
|---------------------|
| ID  | Fecha         |
|---------------------|
| 1   | 16/10/2018    |
|---------------------|
| 2   | 17/10/2018    |
|---------------------|
```

If I enter a new register in the field Fecha for sure Access is going to drop Error 3021 No current record, which is something expected. So instead of showing that error message I want to handle that error. I'm sure this can be handled like exceptions on Java. In that order I may use Try Catch, but I'm new with this, not sure what type of Exception would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate situation that causes error instead of handling it. Use DLookup().

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[Fecha]", "tbl_F", "[Fecha]=#" & Forms!frm_Name!txt_Fecha & "#")) Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Else
    MsgBox "This record already exists"
End If
```

You are showing dates in international format. This might cause issues. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: Yes, the else statement is displayed with both formats dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy, thank you!